# Does deleting a container destroy inside widgets in memory in GTK

Tags: python, gtk3

I'm doing a program in python using GTK3. I have a need to change the GUI interface depending on what the user needs. If I have a window to which I have added a Gtk.Box, and then put something like a label and a text entry in the box and then when needing to change the interface, delete the Box, does that delete the label and text entry in memory? I'm most interesting in Python, but want to learn C as well. Is the answer different for C?

If it doesn't automatically destroy the Gtk.Box, then that means keeping constant track of every widget in the box and needing to call a widget.destroy() for each one. Seems like a bit of a waste.

Thanks,

Narnie

```
>>> import gtk
>>> win = gtk.Window()
>>> vbox = gtk.VBox()
>>> win.add(vbox)
>>> label = gtk.Label("Hello, everybody!")
>>> vbox.pack_start(label, True, True, 0)
>>> win.show_all()
>>> vbox.destroy()
```

Does the vbox.destroy() also destroy the label object?

Comment: I mean does vbox.destroy() destroy the label object NOT the vbox object (corrected above).

Answer (score 6):

When you destroy a container, the widgets inside get their reference count decreased. If a widget's reference count drops to zero, it is destroyed. So if you are not holding any extra references in your code, the widgets will be destroyed when you destroy the container.

In C, there is never any question whether you are holding a reference; if you created the widget and didn't add it to a container yet, or called `g_object_ref()` on the widget, then you have a reference. If not, not.

In Python, things are more complicated. If the widget is bound to a name in the Python interpreter, it probably has an extra reference added. If you are doing things interactively in an interpreter like IPython which keeps track of old inputs, then there are probably several references. But you don't need to worry about that in Python; the garbage collector will remove the references when the object is not reachable anymore, even if it's not destroyed when you destroy the container.

Comment: Thanks, the reason I ask is this. I'm developing that GUI in which the interface changes depending on the user's needs. I was going to create and destroy containers and add a new container back for the interface changes. I had a thought that if the user changes back and forth a lot, this might add a lot of unused objects still in memory if deleting their parent container doesn't destroy them. I think I have decided to just play the widget.show()/widget.hide() game rather than destroying and recreating, but I still would like to know about it.

Comment: @narnie I am trying to develop an application that has the interface change as well did you figure out how to do this?